# Bootstrap datetime picker stepping not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker  with stepping has value 45.But when I increase the minutes ,the hour field increases with 1 hour.

```
$("#startDate").datetimepicker({ format:'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm' , locale: g_state_language, useCurrent: false, stepping: 45, defaultDate: false, sideBySide:true });
```

12:00 to 12:45 is working, but 12:45 increase shows 01:45 instead of 01:30

Comment: Please show full script and if possible create fiddle.

Comment: @David check below my answer with https://jsfiddle.net/darjiyogen/mejtqz6u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetimepicker`'s `stepping` works with rounding step. So to work around your issue, I've added one new options like `forceMinuteStep` into plugin.

[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darjiyogen/mejtqz6u/)

Check below sample how I use `stepping` and `forceMinuteStep` both together to achieve step irrespective of rounding value.

```
// Below changes I made in datetimepicker library.


setValue = function (targetMoment) {
...
...
// Only round if forceMinuteStep is not true otherwise use incremental value directly. 
if (options.stepping !== 1 && !options.forceMinuteStep) {
                    var roundedMins = Math.round(targetMoment.minutes() / options.stepping) * options.stepping;

                    targetMoment.minutes((roundedMins) % 60).seconds(0);
                    targetMoment.minutes((Math.round(targetMoment.minutes() / options.stepping) * options.stepping) % 60).seconds(0);

                }
...
}
```

How I initiated plugin with `forceMinuteStep:true`.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment('03/25/2018 08:45'),
    stepping: 45,
    forceMinuteStep: true
});
```